# Php buffer output, css and mail

Tags: php, css, email, ob-get-contents

Currently I have a script that send some mail, the script result are a couple html tables:

```
$from = "prueba.com <noreply@prueba.com>"; 
$to = "myemail@gmail.com"; 
echo "<div>"; 

$contenido = ob_get_contents(); 
echo "</div>"; 
$cabeceras = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n" 
           ."MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n" 
           ."To: $cliente <$email> \r\n" 
           ."From: prueba <prueba@example.com> \r\n"; 

mail($to,$subject,$contenido,$cabeceras); 

ob_end_flush();
```

As might give css to that email? as I have tried several methods and none has worked.

Thanks in advance for your cooperation

EDIT:

THIS is my CODE http://www.mediafire.com/?bq9352xh6paji1d

Comment: Whats in your $contenido ??? You need to specify css inline

Comment: $contenido is the result of making file_get_contents into an array (several files with glob function) and using strip_tags. The result is some html tables (one html table for file).

Comment: Yes but if you want to style the html either add a HEAD sectiion with the css or att the styling inline as style="" ...

Comment: Already tried that but for some reason the mail result don't admit any css rule.

Comment: You are leaving out the important in your question, you need to provide whats in the output buffer... And I guess you would be helped by using a template to put the contents inside...

Comment: I don't think you understand the difference between html for a web page and html for email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you wanted like this: (using `ob_get_clean()`)

```
ob_start();
echo "<div>"; 
    // more html
echo "</div>";
$contenido = ob_get_clean();
```

and lose the last `ob_end_flush();`

TEST:

```
$from = "prueba.com <noreply@prueba.com>"; 
$to = "myemail@gmail.com"; 
ob_start();
echo "<div>"; 
echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>TEST</td></tr></tr>";
echo "</div>";
$contenido = ob_get_clean(); 

$cabeceras = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n" 
           ."MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n" 
           ."To: $cliente <$email> \r\n" 
           ."From: prueba <prueba@example.com> \r\n"; 

mail($to,$subject,$contenido,$cabeceras);
```

Comment: this script only sent the TEST table but no the script result store in buffer.

Comment: because you need to add html see `// more html` ? in that block you should add you `HTML` code. Understand ?

Comment: not because de mail content is the result of the buffer, the result of all the script operation.

Comment: Then you need to add `ob_start()` where your HTML code starts and `$contenido = ob_get_clean();` where your HTML ends and it will have all html in `$contenido`, now do you understand? :)

Comment: can you see my code (im edit my question) please? I hope you understand if you look that ;)

Comment: then you can add `echo file_get_contents('myfilename.html');` between those `ob_*`

Comment: no, your email is being sent, but if you are using GMAIL it will block your HTML because you have some javascript there and your html title is weird.. remove those ugly characters and it will be sent

Comment: I receibe the email but not with the css, gmail block the css?

Comment: Not most of the css, I tried and I receive with some CSS, functions work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You might take a read here: http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/